# Based on Talmud Bavli Megillah 30a - 30b, how can we have a break betwen Parshiot Zachor and Parah?

Tags: calendar, talmud-bavli, four-parshiot, tractate-megillah

According to what it says in the Talmud, the 3rd of the 4 Shabbatot is Parah, and the Talmud says that this 3rd Shabbat is the one immediately after Purim.

In most years this is true. However, this year, when Pesach falls on Shabbat, and in a year when Pesach falls on Sunday, the Shabbat after Purim is a "break". How / Why did this occur? Is this in contradiction of what the Talmud says?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Megila 30a - 9 lines from the bottom](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9660&st=&pgnum=59) has a dispute as to what is the third Shabbos. The Tanna Kama says the Shabbos immediately after Purim, and Rabbi Chama B'Rab Chanina says it is the Shabbos that is closer to Nissan. The Gemara says there is no dispute, it depends when Rosh Chodesh Nisaan occurs. If it occurs on Shabbos then Parshas Para will be read on the Shabbos just prior to rosh Chodesh Nissan, if Rosh Chodesh Nissan occurs during the week then Parshas Para is read on the Shabbos right after Purim. Thus there is no contradiction.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_43543_624.pdf